# iOS SwiftLint Identifier Name doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftlint

https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/identifier_name.html

Hello.
I recently encountered swiftlint and learned this. But there's a problem. I modified the Identifier Name of swiftlint to maintain the CalmelCase grammar, but it didn't work.

this is my .swiftlint.yml text.

```
identifier_name:
    allowed_symbols: ["_"]
    validates_start_with_lowercase: false
    min_length:
        warning: 1

disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
    - colon
    - comma
    - control_statement

opt_in_rules: # some rules are only opt-in
    - empty_count
    - missing_docs
    # Find all the available rules by running:
    # swiftlint rules

included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
    - Source

excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
    - Carthage
    - Pods
    - Source/ExcludedFolder
    - Source/ExcludedFile.swift
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLYuc.png)

```
import UIKit

class timeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func clickDone(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHRWC.png)

An error is still occurring whether 'validates_start_with_lowercase' is true or false.
What kind of mistake did I make?

Comment: please no images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the rules for identifiers but the rule that is triggering is for [type names](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/type_name.html).

Type names should start with an uppercase letter.

Change your class name to `TimeVC`

```
import UIKit

class TimeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func clickDone(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You shouldn't change the `identifier_name` rules either. If you are going to violate such a basic element of Swift style there probably isn't much point in even using the linter.

Comment: Oh!
I thought 'identifier_name' was in charge of everything.
The option of 'type name' was what I wanted.
Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Ok, but *don't change it!*

Comment: Yes. I understand what you mean.
Thank you.